# Adding custom windowsPhone manifest attributes with cordova

Tags: windows, cordova, cross-platform, manifest, uwp

I am developing Cordova app on vs 2015 Community and I'm struggling with windows manifest configurations. 
I need to add "publisher display name" and "publisher ID" declarations in my manifest, but I can't find a way to implement it...
I've read that such features can be added under  section in the config.xml file :

```
<widget>
    ...
  <preference name="windows-publisher-id" value="CN=My_GUID" />
  <preference name="windows-publisher-display-name" value="My_Display_Name" />" 
    ...
```

Anyhow, it doesn't modifies my manifest as I publish the application.

I've tried to override the auto generated manifest by Cordova by adding manually manifest to ../res/native/windows directory.

Still, no effect...

This is config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget defaultlocale="en-US" id="..."version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps">

  <name>...</name>
  <description>
  </description>
  <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">....</author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <access origin="*" />
  <vs:features />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />

   <preference name="windows-publisher-id" value="CN=My_GUID" />
  <preference name="windows-publisher-display-name" value="My_Display_Name" />" 


  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />

  <platform name="android">
...
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
...

  <platform name="windows">
    ...
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
...
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
 ...
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
  ...
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
...
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
   ....
  </platform>

  <vs:plugin .... />

  <vs:platformSpecificValues>
    <vs:platformSpecificWidget id="....h" platformName="windows" version="...">
      <vs:name>....</vs:name>
    </vs:platformSpecificWidget>
  </vs:platformSpecificValues>
  <access origin="....." />
</widget>
```

Comment: Please post your entire `config.xml`

Comment: I have solved this problem - adding the manifest manually to ../res/native/windows  directory does take an effect, however some of the properties are overridden by config.xml - so that's why it was so confusing.... Sorry I didn't wrote earlier, thank you.

Comment: Still, adding preference  to widget doest works.. I'll post my config.xml